# Connection refused [Remmina][Linux]

Tags: linux-mint, rdp

I have a problem with Linux Mint and the Remmina software. It was working before I updated my system.
below the logs when I want to launch an RDP on my PC in Windows:

```
root@kevin-Aspire-ES1-311:~# flatpak run org.remmina.Remmina
Remmina plugin glibsecret (type=Secret) has registered but not yet initialized/activated. Initialization order is 2000.
[glibsecret] unable to get secret service: Error spawning command line ?dbus-launch --autolaunch=f3d85c83fd6e458aba76dbf56f683032 --binary-syntax --close-stderr?: Child process exited with code 1
StatusNotifier/Appindicator support: not supported by desktop. libappindicator will try to fallback to GtkStatusIcon/xembed
Warning: Remmina is running without a secret plugin. Passwords will be saved in a less secure way.

(org.remmina.Remmina:2): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:47:26.107: gtk_menu_attach_to_widget(): menu already attached to GtkMenuItem

(org.remmina.Remmina:2): libappindicator-WARNING **: 10:47:26.359: Unable to get the session bus: Erreur lors de la génération de la ligne de commande « dbus-launch --autolaunch=f3d85c83fd6e458aba76dbf56f683032 --binary-syntax --close-stderr » : Le processus fils s’est terminé avec le code 1

(org.remmina.Remmina:2): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: 10:47:26.360: Unable to get session bus: Erreur lors de la génération de la ligne de commande « dbus-launch --autolaunch=f3d85c83fd6e458aba76dbf56f683032 --binary-syntax --close-stderr » : Le processus fils s’est terminé avec le code 1
[10:47:45:553] [2:13] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpdr
[10:47:45:553] [2:13] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx rdpsnd
[10:47:45:553] [2:13] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx cliprdr
[10:47:45:553] [2:13] [INFO][com.freerdp.client.common.cmdline] - loading channelEx drdynvc
[10:47:46:977] [2:13] [INFO][com.freerdp.primitives] - primitives autodetect, using optimized
[10:47:46:978] [2:13] [ERROR][com.freerdp.codec] - Failed to create OpenH264 decoder
[libopenh264 @ 0x7fdb58203d00] Unable to create decoder
[10:47:46:985] [2:13] [ERROR][com.freerdp.codec] - Failed to open libav codec
[10:47:46:985] [2:13] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.codecs] - Failed to create h264 codec context
libfreerdp returned code is 00000000

(org.remmina.Remmina:2): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:49:28.790: gtk_menu_detach(): menu is not attached
```

another log :

```
[RDP] Ignoring proxy environment variables
[glibsecret] password "password" deleted for file /home/kevin/.var/app/org.remmina.Remmina/data/remmina/group_rdp_home_192-168-0-41-3389.remmina
[glibsecret] password "ssh_password" deleted for file /home/kevin/.var/app/org.remmina.Remmina/data/remmina/group_rdp_home_192-168-0-41-3389.remmina
[glibsecret] password "gateway_password" deleted for file /home/kevin/.var/app/org.remmina.Remmina/data/remmina/group_rdp_home_192-168-0-41-3389.remmina
```

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar looking issue and managed to fixed it with:

```
flatpak install org.freedesktop.Platform.openh264
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem:

```sh
snap install remmina
```

Install the snap version of remmina and after installation go to 'advanced' in edit option. Increase the connection time out value to 30000.

[image]